# Bitwise AND operator(&) doesn't works as I expected it to work

Tags: java, android, and-operator

I brought the characteristic property which is 10 into int variable charaProp.

`final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();`

And I brought the filtering property which is 2(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) into int variable property.

`final int property = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ;`

I bitwise ANDed charaProp and property to see which one, read or write, to perform.

`final int tmp = charaProp & property;`

Too weird, the AND operator of which the result should be 0,  produces 2.
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wled.jpg)

And flow goes to perform read action.

```
 if ((charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
             mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
 }
```

I really don't know why this happens?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well, 10 in binary is 1010 and 2 in binary is 0010 so the answer 2 is correct.

Comment: 10, in binary, is 2+8, which is 1010.  Two in binary is 10.  Sending them **should** produce binary 10, which is 2.  Your code is working correctly.

Comment: woops!! thanks...I didn't notice 10 was in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing strange about it:

```
     DEC  BIN
   a  10: 1010
   b   2: 0010
  a&b  2: 0010
```

The bitwise operator `&` takes the binary representation of two numbers and performs `bit-and` on those bits.

`a&b` will result in 0 in case:

- a==0 || b == 0
- a, b differ on each but where one of them has a bit set.

**HINT**:
I have a very important hint for you. Do NOT assume that Java is not working in a way it should. It's probably an issue in your code logic. Your title should be: *Java operator & not working as I expected it to work*. In the end, Java always works according to the specification. The problems are always with logic. Sometimes obvious, sometimes logic and knowledge about how the computers (and JVM) work.

Answer (score 0):

10 in binary is `1010`. 2 in binary is `10`. `10 & 1010 = 10` = 2 in base 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior. Look at the binary representations of these numbers.

```
10 == 0b1010
```

That's 8 (0b1000) + 2 (0b10). So 10 & 2 == 2. Try it out:

```
assert 0b1010 & 0b0010 == 2;
```

The & operator lines up the bits and does a logical *and* for each pair. Clearly, the second least significant bit in both 10 and 2 is 1. So if we think of the second bit as a boolean, `true && true == true`.